# php how to get xml content from Google URL

Tags: php, get

I tried with simple_xml_file() and file_get_contents();
But it is not working.

My Input URL:http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=php

Comment: Can you include a snippet showing the code you've already tried?  Do you want to load the xml as a string or as a queryable xml structure?

Comment: any way which i can get data from it. Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure your not just looking for SimpleXMLElement.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=php'));
var_dump($xml);
```

Use rawurlencode on the value not on the name.

```
$url = http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=' . rawurlencode('php tutorial');
```

Comment: Thanks u! But how to get URL with space query.
I Tried:
$url=urlencode('....&q=php tutorial');
But it's not working